# Easy method to move rows from df to another with coditions?

Tags: python, pandas

```
ListOfNames = ['AA', 'BA', CF']
```

df:

```
ID Name Gene Chr Info
1  DD   S     3   441
2  AA   S     5   444
3  DD   F     3   744
4  DD   VV    1   448
5  BA   S     3   445
```

I need to delete all rows from Name same like in a list and move it to another df.

I do something like that:

```
newDF= pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(ListOfNames )):
    a = df.where(df.Name == ListOfNames[i]).dropna()
    newDF= newDF.append(a[0:])
```

In old df should stay all rows without deleted. Deleted should be move to new df. My code return empty df and I don't know why.

If I run:

`a = df.where(df.Name == ListOfNames[1]).dropna()`

I got normally row from df with AA name.

Why it's doesn't works?

Comment: Isn't this simply `df[df['Name'].isin(ListOfNames)]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the isin function:

```
df = df[~df.Name.isin(ListOfNames)]
```

Comment: Damn, so simple... Thank u very much. I need to more practice with pandas to not `for`ed everything :D